# What is the purpose of the dct argument of a metaclass __init__ method?

Tags: python, python-2.x, metaclass

Given a Python 2 metaclass defined as:

```
class Meta(type):
  def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
    pass
```

what is the purpose of the `dct` argument? Based on what I've found, it contains identical information to `cls.__dict__`. The difference being that making changes to `dct` has no effect on the concrete class but adding things to `cls.__dict__` (i.e. by `cls.__dict__['a']=True` or `cls.a=True`) will have an effect.

```
class Meta(type):
  def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
    cls.a = True
    dct['b'] = True

class Test(object):
  __metaclass__ = Meta

t = Test()
print t.a
print t.b  # Raises an AttributeError
```

Are there situations where they are different?

Answer (score 3):

The `dct` parameter provides you with the original class namespace, so it's not really used in the metaclass `__init__` as the class was already created in `__new__`. The `dct` and `cls.__dict__` might be equal, but they are not the same dictionary. It can be useful in a situation where you might need the information contained in the original namespace, without any manipulation performed by the `__new__` method or by parent metaclasses.

They might be different if the `__new__` method is adding attributes to the class -- after its creation -- that weren't in the original namespace.

Comment: If entries are added to `dct` in `__new__` before the call to `super(..).__new__()` then `dct` in `__init__` will contain it. If, however, the `super().__init__` call is made and *then* something is added to `dct` then inside `__init__` it will be present in `dct` but not in `cls.__dict__`. Either way, the `dct` parameter to `__init__` has been changed from the original class namespace.